# Is והבאת in the gerund form?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, masechet-peah

In the משנה פאה א:א, in the phrase והבאת שלום, is the word והבאת a הפעיל  gerund?

Regards,

Ben

Comment: As opposed to what?

Comment: As apposed to an הפעיל imperative.

Comment: I'm guessing by your reply that it is a הפעיל gerund?

Comment: Can you please translate the phrase in a way that would present a gerund in the phrase? The only way I can think of it as a noun is as a noun phrase hava'at shalom so instead of its being "the bringing of peace" it becomes "peace bringing." Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Gerund = Bring of peace.  
Command = Bring peace.

Comment: I am using www.pealim.com to help me correctly translate the word. However I cannot find the same vowels used in the Mishnah וַהֲבָאַת.